# discrepancy between number of cores and thermal zones in `/sys/class/thermal/`

Tags: ubuntu, temperature

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 system with 8 cores:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep ^processor | wc -l
8
```

Yet, I see 11 thermal zones under `/sys/classes/thermal`:

```
ls /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone* | wc -l
11
```

The thermal zones are named `thermal_zone0` to `thermal_zone10`.

Why this discrepancy and is there a way to obtain a single temperature metric (e.g. temperature of hottest core)? I need a single metric as I want to display it on the [i3wm](http://i3wm.org/) status bar. Displaying 11 temperatures would be cumbersome plus I am not sure how these correspond to the 8 cores.

## update

The types of the eleven (11) thermal zones are reported as follows:

```
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/type 
acpitz
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/type 
acpitz
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone2/type 
INT3400 Thermal
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone3/type 
TMEM
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone4/type 
TAMB
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone5/type 
TAM2
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone5/type 
TAM2
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone6/type 
TNGF
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone7/type 
TEFN
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone8/type 
TSKN
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone9/type 
T_VR
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone10/type 
x86_pkg_temp
```

This is confusing rather than elucidating as I now can't tell which thermal zones correspond to the 8 CPU cores.

Comment: Some PCI devices may have their own thermal zones (my video card has one).  This is not really a solution but (in most cases) if you `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/type` and it will give you `acpiz` (or something starting with that) you have a CPU/motherboard sensor.  Other sensors use different names.  I may be wrong, I'm no hardware naming expert.

Comment: @grochmal I have updated the question with the reported types of the thermal zones.

Comment: I wouldn't expect each core to have a temperature sensor. I think the CPU temperature sensor is x86_pkg_temp (pkg = package = a physically distinguishable chip on the motherboard (or daughter board)).

Answer (score 9):

I can confirm [Gilles' comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304845/discrepancy-between-number-of-cores-and-thermal-zones-in-sys-class-thermal#comment535538_304845): the CPU temperature (the hottest core) is given by x86_pkg_temp.

So if

```
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone10/type 
x86_pkg_temp
```

then `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone10/temp` is the file that should be used in your i3 status bar.

As a side note, the temperature of each core can be read in `temp*_input` files in `/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon*/`. The associated `temp*_label` shows which file is related to which core (4 cores in my case):

```
.../hwmon*/$  grep "" temp*_label
temp1_label:Physical id 0
temp2_label:Core 0
temp3_label:Core 1
temp4_label:Core 2
temp5_label:Core 3
```

The file `temp1_input` corresponds to the hottest value of the cores.